# Dynamically change displayed angular child component

Tags: angular

I have a parent component in which I have set up an array of child components (each extending BaseChild).  I use an *ngFor to loop through the children and display their name. I would like to click on the name of the child and insert the html of the child into the parent.  However I don't want to hardcode a lot of `*ngIf={{child1ShouldBeDisplayed}}` in the parent html - there will be a lot of children and things will get very ugly.

I've tried using `ng-content` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287411/modal-component-update-content-child-component-dynamically) but it seems that this is for injecting parent html into the child (from [here](https://medium.com/@joshblf/wtf-is-ng-content-8382b2a664e1)).  I've read through a description of `ng-template, ng-container` etc [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ng-template-ng-content-ng-container-and-ngtemplateoutlet-4b7b51223691/) but it doesn't seem to meet my needs.

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-display-child-content-in-parent?file=src/app/parent/parent.component.html) which sets up the basic code.  I'm not sure how to continue.  Is there a way to choose which child to display in the parent without the use of loads of *ngIf statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great [tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) for this on the official Angular site, with a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bydvgpxaabj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fad-banner.component.ts) example.

### Summary

You need to create a directive. You'll apply your components dynamically through this directive:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[dynamic-stuff]',
})
export class DynamicStuffDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

You need a reference to this element (`<ng-emplate dynamic-stuff></ng-template>`):

```js
@ViewChild(DynamicStuffDirective, {static: true}) dynamicStuff: DynamicStuffDirective;
```

You have to create a component factory for your component:

```js
const componentFactory =
  this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(selectedComponent);
```

You have to apply it through the viewContainerRef of the directive:

```js
this.dynamicStuff.viewContainerRef.clear();
this.dynamicStuff.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

Good luck, I hope I could help.